# How to quickly clean car windows from road salt?

Tags: cleaning, winter, car

## Winter stinks.

For those of us who drive on heavily salted roads, **how do you clean off your windows from the salt?**

Of course, there are wipers on the front, but what about the sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Winter is freezing cold but there's snow!

This leads to a hack that quite often helped me to clean those parts of my car that are not exposed to the windscreen wiper's washing fluid.

I often just use a snow ball to remove salt and dirt from the side windows and the spotlights.

[image]
<sup>[Pixabay](http://pixabay.com/)</sup>

This works best in case it is not too cold outside or if the car was already heated.

We could also use warm water or a windows cleaner to wash off the salt, but it may not be available or it freeze the minute we had applied it if the car was not heated up. There also is quite a risk that the water will flow into the door handle, the key lock or other parts that may get stuck on freezing.

Comment: You have spotlights on your car? cool!

Answer (score 2):

On clear days it is important to go to a car wash and wash fender wells. Otherwise salt will eat into the body. Road salt is corrosive. While there, wash the windows, too. Short of that, the window cleaners at the filling station have a scrubber on one side and a squeegee on the other. These work real well. Follow up with the paper towels provided.